# max-height crops an image from the bottom, how to crop it from the top?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height, carousel

Having this html/css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    <style>
img {
max-height: 100px;
overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="http://www.wwwwwww.com//photos/foto.PNG" />

</body>
</html>
```

We have this result

[image]

Modifying the css like this:

```
img {
max-height: 75px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

We have this result

[image]

What do I have to do to get this result?:

[image]

I found the clip property, but I am using a Bootstrap carousel, and I would like to implement this required method on this element, Do you know if it's possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but by wrapping it in a `<div>` tag with a few css properties, you can achieve the effect.

I'm not in love with the static nature of the sizing, so if you need something more dynamic, keep looking, but this should get you started.

https://jsfiddle.net/e9jmrkkn/25/

Comment: Please explain your down vote. My answer (which, as I stated wasn't perfect), provided a solution. If you think it's bad, propose something better.